# How to add CSS property for firstchild with AngularJS (jqLite)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I want to add `css` to the first `<div>` element (firstChild) inside of a `<div>` with a specific `id`. How can I achieve this with AngularJS (jqLite).

My **HTML** looks like this:

```
<div id="modulare">
   <div class="ibox-content ibox-content">
     ...
   </div>
   <div class="ibox-content ibox-content">
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

My AngularJS (does not work even without selection the first child):

```
if (angular.element('#modulare .ibox-content')){ // I need the first child here
    angular.element('.ibox-content').css("border", "none");
}
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: use ng-class directive

Comment: `#modulare .ibox-content:first` may help

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: @madalinivascu I need to do it with jqLite..

Comment: @31piy nope, does not work :(

Comment: @Fissio doesn't work either

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained why you can't simply solve this by using regular css?

Comment: @Hannes ..because I need to do more stuff inside the if statement and I can't do that with regular css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if (angular.element('#modulare.ibox-content').first()){ // I need the first child here
    angular.element('#modulare.ibox-content').first().css("border", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Certain ways of doing this but in your way you can try:

```
    if (angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('ibox-content'))){ // I need the first child here

angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('ibox-content')).css("background-color", "red");
    }
```

Through css :
take a class with no border

```
.noborder{
border:none !important;
 }
```

You must have ng-class in your html :

```
 <div class="ibox-content ibox-content" ng-class="newclass">
```

In your controller you can add this class whenever you dont want border:

```
$scope.newclass='noborder';
```

Important :  code is not tested. created according to your needs